# JavaScript - Chrome open new window, audio autoplay

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

When I use JavaScript to open a streaming audio window, it refuses to autoplay on Google Chrome (Version 67.0.3396.99).

I've set the attribute "autoplay" on the  element

`<audio id="stream" controls autoplay>`

and I've even tried to use embedded JavaScript in the page to

`document.getElementById("stream").play();`.

The problem is that Chrome blocks any `play()` interaction because

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

Does anyone have a suggested solution for me?

EDIT: Setting muted on the  element doesn't help, because it still requires an additional click to then unmute the audio.

Thanks

:-)

Comment: add `muted="muted"` and see

Comment: I've edited my question ---> "Setting muted on the element doesn't help, because it still requires an additional click to then unmute the audio."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a codesnippet with prop `muted` added and its not showing up any error. Check and let me know and here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/9ng3tszq/

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
 var player1 = document.getElementById("player");
 player1.play();
})
```

```html
<audio id="player" controls autoplay muted>
   <source src="http://d2cstorage-a.akamaihd.net/wbr/gotnext/8578.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Comment: I've edited my question ---> "Setting muted on the element doesn't help, because it still requires an additional click to then unmute the audio."

Comment: if you don't want the additional click, then once the audio starts playing you can remove the prop unmute..Are you looking for that kind of hack

Comment: When I click on "-> Run Code Snippet" on the answer, autoplay works. 

When I click on the jsFiddle, autoplay doesn't work.

When I try it on my own, autoplay doesn't work.
I'm trying `<audio id="stream" controls autoplay muted>`

Comment: @JackWilson for me everywhere its auto-playing even though it's taking a small delay initially.

Comment: Nope, it's still as I stated in my previous comment.

Comment: @JackWilson in SO, you are clicking the `Run Code Snippet` button, that may be the reason it started playing. Similarly click on `Run` button in JS fiddle